# AJAX setInterval bug

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

kindly check sample here in this link: [My test code](http://testcodered.azurewebsites.net/setinterval.php)

This will be used on a div on my actual site and had same problems. As you can see each 2 seconds the div blinks or in my test code site the whole page then when you scroll down it will scroll up automatically with the same time. Obviously it was caused by the setInterval.

Also I'm getting console error:

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.

Is there any way to improve this?

Also, are there other ways to present updated list from database with ui in every second?

Here are my codes:

```
<div id="container"></div>
<script>
    function refreshNews()
    {   $.get('../php/ajaxreportall.php').success(function(data){
             $("#container").html(data);
        })
    }
    refreshNews();
    setInterval(refreshNews, 2000);
</script>
```

the script file

```
<?php 
    require("database.php");

    $sql = "SELECT * from Report r inner join reddb.User_Info u 
            on u.user_email = r.user_email ";

    $res = odbc_exec($conn,$sql);

    echo "
            <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='../css/homelayout.css'>
            <script src='../js/home.js'></script>
        ";

    while($feedItem = odbc_fetch_array($res))
    {
        echo "
            <div class='feedItem'>
                <div>Report No. <label class='feedItemRepID'>" . $feedItem['report_id'] . "</label></div>
                <div>Name:  <label>" . $feedItem['firstname'] . "</label></div>
                <div>Contact No: <label>" . $feedItem['contact'] . "</label></div>
                <div>Details:  <label>" . $feedItem['report_detail'] . "</label></div>
                <div>Date: <label>" . $feedItem['date_report'] . "</label></div>
                <div class='buttons'>
                    <button class='btn btn-success btnRespond' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#myModal'>Respond</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            ";

    }

?>
```

Comment: If you're going to rewrite the entire page HTML (or most of it) on every internal, then it's just going to look ugly and flash and scroll.  You could preserve the scroll position by saving it, adding new content, then setting the scroll back, but the ugly flash is likely not going to disappear.  The nicer way to display updates is to get JSON data from your site for only the data that has changed and then apply only those changes to your screen.  Or get all the data in JSON and update only the data values.  Rewriting the entire HTML of the page is always going to look ugly.

Comment: That's what I'm also thinking since the script is the one who created the html content and every time its just refreshing the page that's why it blinks LOL

Comment: Have a look at my updated answer for a less intrusive version.

Comment: I was trying out your old answer but I haven't push it yet on my azure, let me try your updated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a good idea to use interval to Ajax. Instead change to this:

```
function refreshNews() {   
  $.get('../php/ajaxreportall.php').success(function(data){
    $("#container").html(data);
    setTimeout(refreshNews, 2000);
  });
}
$(function() {
  refreshNews();
});
```

or test if the data changed:

```
var rfn="";
function refreshNews() {   
  $.get('../php/ajaxreportall.php').success(function(data){
    if (rfn!=data) {
      $("#container").fadeOut(function() {
        $("#container").html(data);
        $("#container").fadeIn();
      });
      rfn=data;
    }
    setTimeout(refreshNews, 2000);
  });
}
$(function() {
  refreshNews();
});
```

If you want the above to never stop, even when failing, use .always

```
function refreshNews() { 
  var jqxhr = $.ajax('../php/ajaxreportall.php')
  .done(function(data){
    if (rfn!=data) {
      $("#container").fadeOut(function() {
        $("#container").html(data);
        $("#container").fadeIn();
      });
      rfn=data;
    }
  })
  .fail(function() {
    console.log( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    setTimeout(refreshNews, 2000);
  });
}
```

Comment: the second one worked :bd thank you very much! is there a more cleaner way? I was thinking if the php script would just produce json then will get by ajax to produce the html content... is it correct and cleaner?

Comment: It is correct and cleaner. Always better to only transfer data

Comment: And I tested out to receive new reports and it didn't affect any problems... but I didn't tested it out if report is gone... still a thank you!

Comment: You can use $.ajax(...).always(....) see [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jqXHR) and my update

Answer (score 0):

That error states that you are trying to make synchronous calls which is deprecated, you might have something like this in your code:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   async: false
 });
```

either remove this or change it to true, to remove this error message.

About that scrolling and flickering issue:
for refreshing your news content you are refreshing your complete HTML, so your complete HTML loads again and again. 
Think it like this: you are climbing a ladder, and suddenly the ladder disappears and a new ladder appears? what will happen to you? you will fall back to the starting point i.e ground, scratching your head that what just happened? 
Same thing is happening with scrolling, user scrolls through the news content and it suddenly reloads, and the user is back to starting point.

To solve this you have to refactor everything, you will have to append new news to the list, and will have to store some identifier to identify your last post, you will send this identifier to server, your server will then send only that data which is newer than that post and will also send an identifier to the latest post in response.

Comment: I don't have anything like that in my code. Isn't that the default value is true?

Comment: yes default is true, but the error message says otherwise.

Comment: but I don't really have that code though... how to force it to true otherwise?

Comment: It doesn't matter, because it is just a warning... even if you find the actual reason behind it and solve it, it won't solve your real problem that is scrolling and flickering..